# non-paired bracks break indent in vim

Tags: vim

It seems that latex-suite do the auto indent wrong when there are no closed bracks, for example, in the following $[0,1)$ is the cause of problem:

```
\begin{equation}
    f(x),\quad x\in[0,1)
\end{equation}
```

will indent to

```
\begin{equation}
    f(x),\quad x\in[0,1)
    \end{equation}
```

is there a way to solve it? (if I replace $[0,1)$ with $[0,1]$ then the indent work again).

**UPDATE**
I just install one plugin, i.e., `vim-latex` or `latex-suite` (is this the old name?). And after a while, I found the problem is caused by these lines in `vim-latex\indent\tex.vim`

```
    if g:tex_indent_brace
  " Add a 'shiftwidth' after a "{" or "[" while there are not "}" and "]"
  " after them. \m for magic
    if line =~ '\m\(\(\[[^\]]*\)\|\({[^}]*\)\)$'
        "let ind = ind + &sw
    endif
  " Remove a 'shiftwidth' after a "}" or "]" while there are not "{" and "["
  " before them. \m for magic
    if cline =~ '\m^\(\([^[]*\]\)\|\([^{]*}\)\)'
        "let ind = ind - &sw
    endif
endif
```

as you can see, I comment out two lines of `if...endif`, and which will stop indent for `{` and `[`. And my example will output (do `gg = G`):

```
\begin{equation}
    f(x),\quad x\in[0,1)
\end{equation}
```

BUT, it also mess up something, such as

```
\newcommand{set}[1]{%
\left\{#1\right\}%
}
```

rather than

```
\newcommand{set}[1]{%
  \left\{#1\right\}%
}
```

so, there still need some solution to fix this.

Comment: Try on vim.stackexchange.com if folks don't answer here.  What if you add ` ℅}` to the end of the offending line?

Comment: can you clarify: are you using `latexindent` to do the indentation? or are you using another tool? I can confirm the behaviour you describe using `latexindent`

Comment: if you're using `latexindent`, then I can provide a number of fixes; you might also have a look at `Section 4.5: An important example` in the documentation :) It's very similar to your question

Comment: @cxw If I add `%}` at the end of that line, then no indent of that line.

Comment: @cmhughes I don't know `latexindent`, is it a plugin independent to `vim-latex` or `latex-suite`? I only use `latex-suite` and do the recommand setting as said in the official site.

Comment: @cmhughes I didn't find your section, it seems that `:help latex-suite.txt` has no section 4.5.

Comment: I was referencing latexindent documentation; it sounds like you're not using it, so it would be best to remove the latexindent tag from your question

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Vim 7.4 and Latex Suite at commit `e6972ac` from 2017-12-09.